# Prestashop : Adding a field to choose Shipping carrier in product page front office

Tags: prestashop

I'm using PrestaShop 1.5.5.0.
I want to add a custom check box list to the product page so a customer can choose shipping carrier on the product details page. Can it be possible ? I can add a specific fields in the product details page. As I'm new it's little difficult for me to figure out how can I add other details and carry the values to the order page and that is also dynamically. Is there any module available by which I can accomplish the task ? Please suggest me.

What I want to do is this : Choosing shipping carrier in product page :
http://www.wayfair.com/LifeStyle-Solutions-Zurich-Platform-Bed-LS3-ZUR-X-CP-LF1087.html

Answer (score 1):

Well It's a tough task. You need to work on the controller if you want to carry the values or create a module like shipping estimate and hook it to the product page that might work.